# pysftp not connecting to server. No error message. python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7, pysftp

Python 3.7.4
Idle 3.7 32-bit

I am attempting to connect to an SFTP and download a .CSV file to a local network drive. When I run my code, I get no error message, but nothing prints in the shell and nothing is being downloaded to my local directory.

```
import pysftp
import time


def SFTP_Get_File():
    cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()
    cnopts.hostkeys = None
    host='ServerName'
    user='FakeUser'
    pw='FakePassword'

    with pysftp.Connection(host,
                           username=user,
                           password=pw,
                           cnopts = cnopts
                           ) as sftp:
        print("Connection succesfully stablished ... ")
        sftp.get('/upload/File_Name.csv', r'Local_File_Name.csv')

    time.sleep(2)
    sftp.close()
```

Expected Results is I get a print of connection success and the file in the SFTP downloads to my local directory.

Actual Results. Nothing happens.

Comment: do you have line of code which runs `SFTP_Get_File()` ?

Comment: I have only used the sftp.get()  to try to grab the file.

Comment: is this all your code ? You defined function `SFTP_Get_File()` but you don't run it - so it never run `print()` to display message.

Comment: @furas - you are correct. I was not calling the function... #facepalm

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are defining the function  SFTP_Get_File but you are not calling it.

Try adding

`SFTP_Get_File()`

to the bottom of your script and running it.